# Error in Google visualization bar chart API in Android Browser

Tags: asp.net, android, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization, android-browser

I am using `ASP.NET MVC3, Razor, jQuery Mobile` and having some `java scripts` which calls `Google Chart API`, to draw **Bar Chart (Visualization API)**. It is working fine on Desktop browsers but failing with strange errors in Android Browsers.

**"Cannot read property 'appendchild' of null."**

Java script code is inside "Body" element. following is the code:-
I tried to run it without master page, which include `jquery mobile script` files, same behavior, so `jquery mobile` is not to blame.

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Insight.CloudWeb.ViewModels.KeyFigureViewModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "KeyFigures";
Layout = null;
```

}

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart","table"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        @foreach (var obj in Model)
        {
            @: data.addColumn('number', '@obj.Description  @obj.Value');
        }
        i  = 0;
         data.addRows(1);

        @foreach (var obj in Model)
        {
            @: data.setCell(0, i, @obj.Value);

            @: i = i +1;
        }
        var chartBar = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chartBar.draw(data, { height: 340, width: 500, title: 'Key Figures', chartArea: {left: 2, top: 2}, colors:['blue','red','green','yellow','orange','purple'],legend: 'right' });
    }

</script>    
<div id='chart_div'>
</div>
<div id='table_div'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Built-in Android Browsers do not support SVG. (It was shocking news for me).
Till 2.4 Gingerbread Android built-in browser has no support for SVG images, and Google visualization generated SVG images.

SVG support started from HoneyComb
http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-honeycombs-browser-supports-svg.html

Till Gingerbread there is no support for SVG images:-
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-2-3-gingerbread-the-browser

found that opera mobile browser support SVG in very nice way on android phones, going to recommend my customers same for time being.